# Gingerbread not receiving Parse.com push message

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I build a push client app using Parse.com SDK.
I can receive push messages on Nexus 5 and 7 which both have Android OS v4.4.2.
But I can't receive push messages on older devices like Samsung Galaxy Ace (v2.3.5)

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!--
  IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" in the lines below
  to match your app's package name + ".permission.C2D_MESSAGE".
    -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.me.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.me.myapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="WolApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.me.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <!-- IMPORTANT: Change "com.parse.starter" to match your app's package name. -->
                <category android:name="com.me.myapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.me.myapp.MyCustomReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.me.myapp.UPDATE_STATUS" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you please post your android manifest?